# Trying to get property of non-object in Job Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create job to register users and tried to follow Jeffrey's video but looks like dispatchfrom is removed for some reason. This is what i'm trying to do now:

This is my controller:

```
public function PostSignUp(Request $request)
{

  dispatch(new RegisterUser($request->all()));
  return 'done';

}
```

This is my job:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class RegisterUser implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $request;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *  @param $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
      $email =   $this->request->email;
      var_dump('I should register user with email:' . $email);
    }
}
```

I also tried to put

just `$request` instead of `$request->all()`

but then i get

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

And now I'm getting `Trying to get property of non-object error.` Is this good way to pass whole request to job ? Should i do it some other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with input()

```
   $request->input()
```

Comment: Yep That did it ! Now i'm getting request as an object

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$request->all()`, that means you are passing an **array** to the job **and not the whole $request**. Therefore, you can simply do this in your Job Handler.

```
public function handle()
{
  $email = $this->request['email'];

  var_dump('I should register user with email:' . $email);
}
```

Let me know if something else is required :)

Comment: Thanks for reply ! But how can i pass whole request object ?

Comment: I just tried your method , now i get same error as before: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Comment: You can not pass the whole request... that is why you are getting the **Serialization of Closure** error. you can only pass the array. To be honest... my method should work if you are using `$request->all()`.

Comment: yeah you were right i removed all() when i was testing it works now. Shame that you can't pass whole request object but this will work for now